# как изменить поле User model id(int(11)) на BigAutoField django

Tags: django, база-данных, django-model

я сейчас поменяю все id(AutoField) в моей базе данных но у меня есть ForeignKey на User model.как поменять его id тоже на BigAutoField.
models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True) 
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Вроде все понятно.в базе данных у меня user_id int(11) как поменять его ?